# pysvn in Autodesk maya's python 2.7.11

Tags: python, maya, pysvn

I'm trying to use pysvn with Maya Python version 2.7.11.

Neither the official `pysvn` installation nor the installation via `maya pip` gave me the desired results.

I tried download `pysvn` for 2.7.11 version in https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/downloads.html

But maya raised error:

```
   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\utils.py", line 386, in formatGuiException
     exceptionMsg = unicode(exceptionObject)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
  Original exception was:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<maya console>", line 4, in <module>
     File "/2.7.11/pysvn/__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
     import _pysvn_2_7
ImportError: DLL load failed:

error in maya script editor.
```

Second try was `mayapy -m pip install pysvn`

But this module had very little functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The official PySvn package is actually called pysvn-wheel.

https://pypi.org/project/pysvn-wheel/

Also note that Maya 2020 launches with Python 3.x I believe, unless you explicitly tell it to run in Python 2.x. Remember to use the proper Python executable to install if you intend to run with Python 2.x - its site-packages is probably at a different location.